# R code to MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

Here is a code in `R`, I would like to run it with `MATLAB`, optimizing if possible.

```
require(lattice)
#
set.seed(42)

# parameters for distribution of class 1
a <- 0
b <- 1
# parameters for distribution of class 2
c <- 3
d <- 1

x <- c(sort(rnorm(1000,mean=a,sd=b)),sort(c(rnorm(1000,mean=c,sd=d))))
y <- c(dnorm(x[1:1000],mean=a,sd=b),dnorm(x[1001:2000],mean=c,sd=d))
labels <- factor(rep(c("class 1","class 2"),each=1000))

dat <- data.frame("x"=x,"density"=y,"groups"=labels)
xyplot(density~x,data=dat,groups=labels,type="b",auto.key=T)
```

Comment: Adding more documentation as to what the different parts do would help.  There are people who know MatLab, but not R.  With these comments they should still be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're plotting two normal distributions. Here's the equivalent in matlab.

```
mu1=0;sigma1=1;   %# parameters for the first distribution
mu2=3;sigma2=1;   %# parameters for the second distribution

%# get density at 1000 points equally spaced between mu-4sigma & mu+4sigma for each class
x1=linspace(mu1-4*sigma1,mu1+4*sigma1,1000);
p1=normpdf(x1,mu1,sigma1);  

x2=linspace(mu2-4*sigma2,mu2+4*sigma2,1000);
p2=normpdf(x2,mu2,sigma2);

%# plot the densities.
plot(x1,p1,x2,p2)
```